# dynamic field const vs. any old reference field const behavior

Tags: c#

This probably has a simple explanation I'm failing to see, but why is the following code legal:

```
    public struct Foo
    {
        const object nullObject = null;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            if (nullObject == null)
            {
                return base.ToString();
            }

        }
    }
```

While the following,

```
    public struct Foo
    {
        const dynamic nullObject = null;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            if (nullObject == null)
            {
                return base.ToString();
            }

        }
    }
```

gives the following compile time error: **Foo.ToString()': not all code paths return a value**?

Why does the fact that `nullObject` being `dynamic` makes the compiler not be able to assert that `nullObject` will always be `null`?

**EDIT**: Expanding on the question, and based on [smoore's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174499/smoore) answer, why does the compiler allow `dynamic` `const` fields to begin with? Isn't it kind of self defeating? I know this scenario has no real application at all and it's frankly quite pointless but I stumbled upon it by sheer accident and just got curious.

Comment: `why does the compiler allow dynamic const fields to begin with?` Because technically it allows `const` to be applied to any type of field. As with any feature the question is not "why didn't they implement this feature that I want?" it's "why should they implement this feature that I want?"  In this case the feature is to explicitly prohibit a `const` field from being `dynamic`.  As with most feature requests, the answer would most likely be, "it just isn't worth the time and effort; there were more important features to add". This is going quite out of your way to shoot yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 6):

Because [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) objects are not resolved at compile time, so the compiler has no idea that it will always be null.  The dynamic object won't be resolved until run time.

**EDIT:**

I see your confusion, why even allow a const dynamic?

My guess is that the Dynamic could be changed to a non-nullable type, in which case ToString would not return a value, but that's just a guess.  I'm also thinking that you might still want to have the ability to have a constant dynamic, so that you can ensure the value won't change outside of the static constructor, but not know the type until run-time.

Another possibility, as Servy point out, is that it's such a corner-case that it's not worth fixing.

Comment: I understand that but then, why allow `dynamic` `const` fields to begin with? The whole point is that `const` can't be more static.

Comment: @Tejas: No, that code won't compile. Reference const fields can only be initialized to `null` except `string` which has always been a special `class`. Value types can only be initialized to constant expressiones to begin with.

Comment: @Tejas Except that `const` values have to be evaluated at compile-time, so they can't call any methods.